# Is there a way to pass data from beforeSave() to afterSave() in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I am working in CakePHP. In the `beforeSave()` I am making a comparison of a column value in the database to the updated column value that is about to be saved. I would like to pass this data to the `afterSave()` callback to determine what the callback does. Is there a way to pass data from the `beforeSave()` to the `afterSave()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with `cakePHP` specifically, but if it's similar to some other MVC frameworks, the `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()` callbacks are executed in a similar context (they belong to the same object -- a model or controller).

If that's the case, a simple solution would be to simply use a custom class property to track your data.

```
private $custom;

beforeSave(){
   // save what you want to access later
   $this->custom = 'comparison result';
}

afterSave(){
   // retrieve what we found in beforeSave()
   $custom = $this->custom;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass arguments to your callbacks `beforeSave(array $options = array())` and `afterSave(boolean $created, array $options = array())` from the `save(array $data = null, array $params = array())` function of the model.

Here is an example

```
//In your controller
$this->Post->save($data, array('arg1' => $value));

//In the Post Model
beforeSave($options = array()){
   // $options contains the arg1 param 
}

afterSave($created, $options = array()){
   // $options contains the arg1 param
}
```

Try it :)